# how to time Fluid flow object emitting fluid?

Tags: physics

Following this very helpful youtube tutorial [Blender Physics - Creating a Splash with Mantaflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKm19oozgNs&ab_channel=CrossMindStudio,)

But then I need to find out how to time this object:
(type: flow, flow type: liquid, flow behavior: Geometry)
to emit fluid at a certain later keyframe, and not at frame 1.

How do you time the emission?

Comment: Animate some properties of the flow emitter, I’d expect.

Comment: You can keyframe the "use inflow" checkbox on the flow object.

Comment: I tried "use inflow" and limited to one frame, and even still, it gushes out 3 or 4 mesh size particles. How can I limit it to just one mesh worth of particles?

Answer (score 0):

It's the Offset under Cache in the domain object. But still not sure how to make each individual flow object have its own offset amount.